# Find a subspace W of $\mathbb{F}^5$ such that $\mathbb{F}^5=U \bigoplus W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Suppose $$U = \{(x,y,x+y,x-y,2x)\in \mathbb{F}^5:x,y\in \mathbb{F} \}$$
if for $(x,y,z,w,s)\in\mathbb{F}^5$ then we choose $$ W = \{(0,0,z-x-y,w-x+y,s-2x)\in\mathbb{F}^5:x,y,z,w,s\in\mathbb{F}\}$$ s.t.
$$(x,y,z,w,s) = (x,y,x+y,x-y,2x)+(0,0,z-x-y,w-x+y,s-2x)$$
thus we see for $(x,y,z,w,s)\in U$ then $x=0,y=0,z=z-x,w=w-x+y,s=s-2x$ or that $x=0,y=0,z=z,w=w,s=s.$ then for $(x,y,z,w,s)\in W$ then,
$$x=x,y=y,z=x+y,w=x-y,s=2x$$ but $x=0,y=0$ from this equation and the above we have $x=y=z=w=s=0$ then $U \cap W=\{0\}$.
so $$\mathbb{F}^5 = U \bigoplus W.$$
This does not seem right, the sheldon axler notion is a bit confusing with the way they labels elements in a vector.

Comment: What doesn't seem right about it?

Comment: I dont know the notion sheldon axler uses is a bit confusing with expressing the vectors, but the arguement when I said x=0 and y=0 from above so x=y=z=w=s=0 so then the intersection is trivial, is that a correct way of showing the sum is direct?

Answer (score 0):

$$U=\left \{  x(1,0,1,1,2)+y(0,1,1,-1,0):x,y\in \mathbb{F} \right \}$$
we have $e_{1}=(1,0,1,1,2),e_{2}=(0,1,1,-1,0)$. You can imagine that $U$ is a two dimensional "plane" spanned by $e_{1},e_{2}$.
So you only need to look for another three vectors $ e_{3},e_{4},e_{5}$ which are linearly independent and these five bases  together span the five dimensional space.It's trivial.$$e_{3}=(1,0,0,0,0),e_{4}=(0,1,0,0,0),e_{5}=(0,0,0,0,1)$$
so that:$$W=\left \{  z(1,0,0,0,0)+w(0,1,0,0,0)+s(0,0,0,0,1)=(z,w,0,0,s):z,w,s\in \mathbb{F} \right \}$$
and it's easy to check that $U \cap W={0}.$